AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags("es")) looks like crash
After setting application locale inside android app, it looks like crashed and restarted. Seems, it is not a good user experience.
Is there any way to get it as smooth transition after application locale change?
I just want smooth transition while locale change happening in the app.
